# Wheatstone Bridge question

Tags: transducer

Need help on Wheatstone bridge circuit.

The question is-

Calculate the value of the distant unknown resistor Rx at the end of a loop,in a Wheatstone Bridge configuration.The three known resistors are each 1Kohm and the short-circuit loop resistance is 75ohm.

I want to know if my equation is correct.

R1 = 1K ohm (1000ohm)
R2 = 1K ohm (1000ohm)
R3 = 1K ohm (1000ohm)
Rx = ?

```
                R1 / R2 = R3 / Rx

   thus  =           Rx = (R2 / R1) x R3    
                        =(1000/1000)x1000
                     Rx = 1000ohm (1K)
```

Feels like something is missing.the question is all together 8 points

And "what is a closed circuit loop resistance"

Comment: so. i have to calculate parallel 1(R2 and Rx), then calculate parallel 2(R1 and R3), add them together to calculate series resistance, and all should equal up to 750ohms?        can you supply a equation please, and thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you misread "750" as "75", and I believe what they're asking for is the value of Rx with the bridge shorted, as shown, which will make Rt equal to 750 ohms.

If that's true, then you need to consider what value of Rx is needed, in parallel with R2, to set R2||Rx, in series with R1||R3, equal to 750 ohms, like this:

[image]

Comment: so. i have to calculate parallel 1(R2 and Rx), then calculate parallel 2(R1 and R3), add them together to calculate series resistance, and all should equal up to 750ohms? can you supply a equation please, and thank you.             i think the book has type error,because its definitely 75 ohm.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to include the formulas.